# Blank area when resizing Chrome running Flash application

Tags: flash, google-chrome

I'm observing an undesirable effect with Chrome and Flash when resizing a window.

I have a full screen SWF application embedded inside HTML with AC_FL_RunContent:

```
AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "my_app",
        "width", "100%",
        "height", "100%",
        "align", "middle",
        "id", "app",
        "quality", "high",
        "bgcolor", "white",
        "name", "app",
        "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
        "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
);
```

When I restore down window size and then maximize it again then the SWF is no longer displayed full-screen - there remains a blank strip on the bottom. It looks as if the Flash panel was resized correctly width-wise, but not at all height-wise.

I can see the problem using Chrome on Windows - both using built-in Flash player and Adobe Flash player. I also tried Chromium for Linux (OpenSuse 13.2) - same problem.
The problem does not appear at all on Firefox or IE11.

Some version numbers:

- Adobe Flex SDK 3.5
- Version number in SWF file: 9 (very old, I know)
- Windows 8.1
- Chrome 41
- Flash Player 17

I can see the same problem with 3rd party Flex 3-based SWF files - e.g. http://www.dlgsoftware.com/flexexrenderers/FlexExrenderers.html, so I believe the problem is not in our HTML/JS/SWF files.

I haven't seen such problems with Flex 4.5-based SWF files, which makes me think it is a compatiblity issue between Flex 3 and Chrome.

Does anyone know if it is a Flex bug or Chrome bug, or something else? Is there any workaround or a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented the same issue!

workaround: 
When you resize the screen using the zoom options, the blank strip disappear and restore the swf

I found the problem on my setup:

In my flex IDE, in my project folder, in html-template folder, I have a file name index.template.html which is use to generate the projectName.html file.

Locate in the file these lines:

```
<style>
    body { margin: 0px; overflow:hidden }
</style>
```

replace them with:

```
<style>
    html, body { height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
    body { margin:0; }
</style>
```

rebuild your project and you're done...

Hope that help!

Comment: Thanks @Eric, it solved the problem - we did exactly as you suggested and the blank area is gone!